# Incomplete pointer array to struct. Stack smashing detected

Tags: c, flexible-array-member

My apologies in advance for the bad-looking code. It's just a proof of concept.

The purpose of the program is to fill the "datapacket", but by individually accessible pointers of the `potmeter` struct.

The program works with a complete type of `*potPointers[3]`. It also works with incomplete type `*potPointer[]`. But then after a successful run, I get:

```
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
```

How do I successfully deal with incomplete pointer arrays to a struct?
I can of course put a `#define`, but is there another way?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BYTES_DATAWORD_POTMETER 2

typedef struct
{
    uint8_t test;
    uint8_t *datawordPointer[2];
}potmeter;

typedef struct
{
    uint8_t amountOfPots;

    size_t datapacket_size;
    uint8_t *datapacket; // needs to be malloc'ed, don't forget to free it.
    
    // Sort of working with *** stack smashing detected ***: terminated Aborted (core dumped)         
    potmeter *potPointers[];

   // Works without stack smashing.
   // potmeter *potPointers[3];     
     
}overall;


void initPointersToDatapackett(overall *allePots)
{ 
    uint8_t counter = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < allePots->amountOfPots; i++)
    {
        // Allocate memory per pot
        allePots->potPointers[i] = malloc(sizeof(potmeter));

        // Point pointers to dataword of overall
        allePots->potPointers[i]->datawordPointer[0] = &allePots->datapacket[counter++];
        allePots->potPointers[i]->datawordPointer[1] = &allePots->datapacket[counter++];
        
    }
}



int main()
{
    overall AllePotMeters;

    AllePotMeters.amountOfPots = 3;
    AllePotMeters.datapacket = malloc(AllePotMeters.amountOfPots*BYTES_DATAWORD_POTMETER);
    

    initPointersToDatapackett(&AllePotMeters);

    //Test content of pointers to dataword
    *AllePotMeters.potPointers[0]->datawordPointer[0] = 'A';
    *AllePotMeters.potPointers[0]->datawordPointer[1] = 'B';
    *AllePotMeters.potPointers[1]->datawordPointer[0] = 'C';
    *AllePotMeters.potPointers[1]->datawordPointer[1] = 'D';
    *AllePotMeters.potPointers[2]->datawordPointer[0] = 'E';
    *AllePotMeters.potPointers[2]->datawordPointer[1] = '\0';


    printf("String test %s\n", AllePotMeters.datapacket);


    free(AllePotMeters.potPointers[0]);
    free(AllePotMeters.potPointers[1]);
    free(AllePotMeters.potPointers[2]);
    free(AllePotMeters.datapacket);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It seems to me that the `potmeter *potPointers[]` is weird. In a data packet I would expect a type like `potmeter potPointers[]`, because you want a contiguous memory buffer to send somewhere. This code makes little sense to me in that regard. You also don't seem to allocate memory for `datawordPointer` anywhere.

Comment: The ```datawordPointer``` points to the ```dataword``` of the overall struct, which is malloc'd.

Comment: `[]` doesn't mean "this array will grow on demand" or "this array magically has enough elements for everything". What do you think it does mean?

Comment: I think I've found a solution. By making ```potPointer``` a double pointer: ```potmeter **potPointers;``` and then malloc the amount of pointers it need.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Yes, you are right. It never knows it size and will be incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature you are using here is called ["flexible array member"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member). If the array size is empty, the size of the `overall` struct doesn't include the array at all. So a variable of `overall` type doesn't contain any memory for your `potPointers`.

It's programmer's responsibility to allocate space for `potPointers`. Note that this usually means allocating the `struct` dynamically, using `malloc`. Then, you (the programmer) can tell it to allocate more memory than `sizeof(overall)`.

For example:

```
overall *AllePotMeters = malloc(sizeof(overall) + 3 * sizeof(potmeter *));
```

If `AllePotMeters` is on stack, the compiler doesn't allocate any memory at all for the flexible array member. So writing to it smashes the stack (i.e. overwrites important data on stack).

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for. Btw is using a double pointer also a good solution? Like this: ``` potmeter **potPointer; potPointers = malloc(3*sizeof(potmeter *)); ```